# Different import behaviour in identical code in interactive vs. non-interactive mode - why does the module search path differ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-2.7

This question is related to [Can't import module with importlib.import_module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410960/cant-import-module-with-importlib-import-module), which I don't think got to the root of the issue at all.

I'm trying to understand the reason for differences with `importlib` used in the interactive interpreter vs. a non-interactive script, because I'm getting different results with each.

I have a folder containing `myscript.py`, and I want it to import a module called `module` from a subfolder, `my_subdir` of the initial working directory. I want to do this by moving into that directory and working there. I know there are other solutions to accessing a module in a subdirectory, but this is the use case that I'd like to talk about.

The following is the contents of `myscript.py`, which simply moves into the subdirectory and tries to import the module from there, and then call some hello-world function from the module:

```
#!/home/chris/anaconda2/bin/python
import sys
import platform
import os
import importlib

print("Python version "+ platform.python_version())
print(sys.path)

os.chdir('my_subdir')
my_module = importlib.import_module('module')
my_module.my_function()
```

When I run this from the command line, Python can't find the module. It seems that the import system doesn't know about the change of directory from `os.chdir()`:

```
(base) chris@linux-om3m:~/workspace> python myscript.py 
Python version 2.7.15
['/home/chris/workspace', '/home/chris/anaconda2/lib/python27.zip', '/home/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7', '/home/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/home/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/home/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/home/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 11, in <module>
    my_module = importlib.import_module('module')
  File "/home/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named module
```

However, when I type the same script into the interactive interpreter, it works fine:

```
(base) chris@linux-om3m:~/workspace> python
Python 2.7.15 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul  2 2019, 00:39:44) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> import platform
>>> import os
>>> import importlib
>>> print("Python version "+ platform.python_version())
Python version 2.7.15
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/home/chris/anaconda2/lib/python27.zip', '/home/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7', '/home/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/home/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/home/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/home/chris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
>>> os.chdir('my_subdir')
>>> my_module = importlib.import_module('module')
>>> my_module.my_function()
Here I am!
>>>
```

I can fix this issue by manually updating `sys.path` with a `sys.path.append(os.getcwd())` after I do the `os.chdir` - but I do not understand why this is only necessary in non-interactive mode.

The only thing I do notice (and is printed here in the pasted output) is that under the interactive interpreter, `sys.path` has an empty-string entry, whereas in non-interactive mode it contains the working dir where I invoked python.

I know I could fix this problem using relative imports, and for now I'm fixing the problem using a `sys.path.append(os.getcwd())`, but I'd like to understand why there is a difference between running interactively vs. non-interactively.

I'm getting the same results with Python 2.7 and Python 3.6.

Comment: Actually, I can also fix it by `sys.path.append('')` in non-interactive mode, so I guess `''` has a special meaning. But the question remains as to why the interactive interpreter has the empty string on `sys.path`, but the non-interactive does not (and thus we have quite different behaviour between the two!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted in your comment, appending `''` to `sys.path` fixes the issue. This is because `''` represents your cwd, so `os.chdir()` knows where to find your subdirectory `my_subdir` correctly (see [Why is the first element in python's sys.path an empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49559003/why-is-the-first-element-in-pythons-sys-path-an-empty-string)).

Using an absolute path for `my_subdir` should also fix your issue.

Comment: This makes sense - but why is the behaviour not the same between the two cases? Why does the non-interactive version not use a `''` too?

Comment: Ah ok https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path - `''` is used if the script directory is not available - e.g. in interactive mode. This makes sense, but ultimately this causes unintended (and surprising!) differing behaviour.